# Where is the mistake in this find method?

Tags: javascript, find

The code works with a simple foreach function, but not with a find method.
Here is the forEach code:

```
getItemById: function (id) {
    let found = null;
    data.items.forEach(item => {
     if (item.id === id) {
      found = item;
     }
    });
    return found;
}
```

Here is the code with a find mehtod:

```
getItemById: function (id) {
      let item = data.items.find(item => {
        item.id === id;
      });
      return item;
    }
```

Why doesn't work the code with the find method?

also here is the array of the objects:

```
const data = {
    items: [
      { id: 0, name: 'Steak Dinner', calories: 1200 },
      { id: 1, name: 'Sausage', calories: 1100 },
      { id: 2, name: 'Eggs', calories: 200 },
    ],
    currentItem: null,
    totalCalories: 0,
  }
```

Comment: .find(item => item.id === id)
or
.find(item => { return item.id === id;})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) expects a predicate function as a callback and return the value that satisfy the condition. If you won't return then `undefined` will return by default and `undefined` is considered as a `falsy` value.

You are not returning anything from the `find` function. `find` will not consider a match if predicate function won't return `true`. There is not a single match that returns `true` in any case because all values returned by `find` is `undefined`

```
return item.id === id.
```

```js
const data = {
  items: [
    { id: 0, name: "Steak Dinner", calories: 1200 },
    { id: 1, name: "Sausage", calories: 1100 },
    { id: 2, name: "Eggs", calories: 200 },
  ],
  currentItem: null,
  totalCalories: 0,
};

const obj = {
  getItemById: function (id) {
    let item = data.items.find((item) => {
      return item.id === id;
    });
    return item;
  },
};

console.log(obj.getItemById(0));
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not returning the boolean inside find's callback

```
let item = data.items.find(item => {
    return item.id === id;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You just forgot the `return` statement in your find function. So it will run through all items and result nothing currently.

So just `return` the result of `item.id === id` and you're fine.

```
let item = data.items.find(item => {
    return item.id === id;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
getItemById: function (id) {
      return data.items.find(item => item.id === id);
    }
```

You don't have to use "{" and ";"  in data.items.find() method. Because,the find is a predicate function

Answer (score 0):

If a lambda function contains a **single expression**, it is *return*ed automatically. (`;` and `{}` are not part of an expression )
Otherwise the `return` statement is a must, to return a value.

`find` accepts a predicate & such it must return a `boolean`.

Either do,

```
let item = data.items.find(item => item.id === id);
```

Or,

```
let item = data.items.find(item => {
    return item.id === id;
});
```